# How to write query which matches string and not equal to 0 for integer value in elastic search

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am new to elastic search. I just started writing queries. What is the best predicate to use to match the below query  (textvalue.value="HeyHow" and totalamount > 0)  in php .

Any help is highly appreciated. TIA

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 5,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "testindex",
        "_type" : "testindex",
        "_id" : "El9eOp515UcTc3",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "El9eOp515UcTc3",
          "user_ud" : "10000000000000",
          "totalamount" : 0,
          "textvalue" : [
            {
              "key" : "he",
              "value" : "qwertyt"
            }
          ],
          "canchage" : false,
          "created_at" : 1588349627
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "testindex",
        "_type" : "testindex",
        "_id" : "El9mKXLwhMNT60",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "El9mKXLwhMNT60",
          "user_ud" : "10000000000000",
          "totalamount" : 0,
          "textvalue" : [
            {
              "key" : "he",
              "value" : "HeyHow"
            }
          ],
          "canchage" : false,
          "created_at" : 1588350044
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "testindex",
        "_type" : "testindex",
        "_id" : "El9oApiJYuf0Wr",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "El9oApiJYuf0Wr",
          "user_ud" : "10000000000000",
          "totalamount" : 0,
          "textvalue" : [
            {
              "key" : "he",
              "value" : "HeyHow"
            }
          ],
          "canchage" : false,
          "created_at" : 1588350142
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "testindex",
        "_type" : "testindex",
        "_id" : "El9wuLOHPyy6cn",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "El9wuLOHPyy6cn",
          "user_ud" : "10000000000000",
          "totalamount" : 1,
          "textvalue" : [
            {
              "key" : "he",
              "value" : "HeyHow"
            }
          ],
          "canchage" : false,
          "created_at" : 1588350638
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "testindex",
        "_type" : "testindex",
        "_id" : "ElA2giaCaGp8ir",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "ElA2giaCaGp8ir",
          "user_ud" : "10000000000000",
          "totalamount" : 100,
          "textvalue" : [
            {
              "key" : "he",
              "value" : "HeyHow"
            }
          ],
          "canchage" : false,
          "created_at" : 1588350966
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried using must for textvalue.value and must not for total amount but it didn't worked.It just getting all results that matching the  textvalue.value

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "totalAmount": {
              "gt": 0
            }
          }
        },
       {
         "nested": {
           "path": "textvalue",
           "query": {
             "match": {
               "textValue.value": "HeyHow"
             }
           }
         }
       }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how do we get the values where totalAmount!=0;

Comment: hi, the above query will fetch only the document that has totalAmount > 0. so that it won't even fetch the document that has totalAmount=0. thus solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
GET testindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "textvalue.value": "HeyHow"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "totalamount": {
              "gt": 0
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

or as a PHP array

```
 [
   "query" => [
         "bool" => [
            "must" => [
               [
                  "match" => [
                     "textvalue.value" => "HeyHow" 
                  ] 
               ], 
               [
                  "range" => [
                       "totalamount" => [
                          "gt" => 0 
                       ] 
                  ] 
               ] 
            ] 
         ] 
      ] 
]
```

Comment: how do we get the values where totalAmount!=0

Comment: `gte: 0` && `lte:0` or use `{"term":{"totalamount":{"value":0}}}`

Comment: how do i write for not equal to zero